# how to define split patterns in sed using spaces

Tags: sed, makefile

I am new to this forum and this is my first query, hope I am not duplicating stuff.

I need to replace the following strings in a C file and I am using Sed for this purpose.

Input:

```
#define  N_MAX_ITEMS 20 // some comment 
#define  N_TOTAL_COUNT    10
```

Expected output:

```
N_MAX_ITEMS = 20
N_TOTAL_COUNT = 10
```

The inputs can have multiple or single spaces or tabs in between.

I am using the following sed command in MAKEfile, to be executed in Cygwin environment.

```
macros_$(HW_TYPE).ini: macros_temp.h    
 rm -f $@
 sed -e "s/\(#define[ \t]*\) \(N_.*\) \([\s\t]*[A-Z0-9_(].*\)/\2=\3/" <$^ >>$@
```

but the output is not proper particularly if for the expression that have comments appended.

The generic idea is, that my sed should be able to select different words till the first space or tab encountered.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^#define\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+).*/\1 = \2/' file
```

Use the metacharacters `\s` and `\S` for whitespace and non-whitespace and the `+` metacharacter for one or more.